# Limitation for speaking words with free nuance API in Pepper Robot?

Tags: pepper, nuance

Is there any limitation for speaking words per month/week with free nuance API version in Pepper Robot?

Answer (score 2):

TTS and ASR is unlimited, but using the ASR Remote Engine (wildcard *) may be limited. I think the limit is 100-200 request per day but I cannot find any source of this.
[ASR Remote Supported languages](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-7/family/pepper_technical/languages_pep.html#remote-asr-engine-list-of-supported-languages)

Comment: Exactly. No limits for TTS. No limits for embedded ASR. But for remote ASR (freespeech/wildcard*) limitations per days exists; dependant of your contracts/offers/profils.